# Simple type products collection - wrong count

Tags: magento-1, collection, simple-product

Here's a collection that should include all simple products in my magento store:

```
$collectionSimple = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple');
```

This collection has 6750 items, while my magento has 9892 simple products.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems out that (enabled) flat catalog is causing this issue. A simple fix is to add this line before the getCollection

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig('catalog/frontend/flat_catalog_product', 0);
```

solution source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30750804/236021

Answer (score 0):

This could occur if you have multiple store views.

Try adding `->addStoreFilter(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)` to load products from the "default" store.

Comment: It's a single store installation. I added your code but I'm getting the same results.